# Calculating entropy Through Huffman Codeword lengths.

Tags: entropy

Given the length of the codeword (i.e. the binary representation of a characters: $1, 1010, 00$, etc.) of each symbol in an alphabet, how could I calculate the bit per symbol entropy?

The particular problem I'm solving has the alphabet $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}$ with the probabilities:

$$P(a_1)=0.4,\quad p(a_2)=p(a_3)=0.2,\quad p(a_5)=p(a_4)=0.1,$$

which has an entropy oh $H(S) = 2.278$ bits/symbol and average length of $L = 2.2$ bits/symbol. Finally the coding is done with no regards to variance, if it helps.

Comment: Please give an example Huffman tree with frequencies in each leaf node, so people can work out the entropy.

Comment: I edit in the particular example i'm working on, hope it has all needed!

Comment: How did you get the entropy $2.278$? I got a smaller number. This number should not exceed $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Huffman tree

$$(a_1,((a_2,a_3 ),(a_4,a_5 ) ) ),$$

in which the codes for the $5$ symbols are $a_1=0$, $a_2=100$, $a_3=101$, $a_4=110$, $a_5=111$. The average word length (bits per symbol)

$$\bar{L}=\sum_{i=1}^5P(a_i)L(a_i)=0.4\times 1+0.6\times 3=2.2$$

as you calculated, and the Shannon entropy (information content) per symbol

$$S=-\sum_{i=1}^5P(a_i)\log_2P(a_i)=\log_210-1.2=2.1219\mbox{ bits}.$$

Huffman code uses on average $2.2$ bits to code $2.1219$ bits of information.

Comment: But let's say the only thing I have is the length of the code for each individual symbol. So you would have 1 for a1 and 3 for the other symbols, is it possible to calculate the Entropy only with that information?

Comment: The same Huffman tree can be applicable to different probabilities, which would then have different entropies. So I think it's impossible.